# segue data transferring is not working. Detailed Data that each character has is not showing

Tags: swift, xcode

I tried to use segue function to reflect the data between viewcontrollers.
After a click on each character, it is supposed to show the detailed data from it.
All I see is the view from the sample in main storyboard
Please give me some advice to correct this codes. Thank you!

```
//first viewcontroller

import UIKit

class SeannyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let namelist = ["don", "mill", "dulu", "hem", "lue", "tine", "whip", "key"]
    let bountylist = [20, 40, 70, 50, 30, 80, 90, 200]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showdetail" {
          let vc = segue.destination as? detail_seannyViewController
            if let index = sender as? Int {
            vc?.name = namelist[index]
            vc?.bounty = bountylist[index]
        }
    }
}
//how many you going to show?

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return namelist.count
    }

//how you make your cell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? ListCell else {

            return UITableViewCell()
        }

        let img = UIImage(named: "\(namelist[indexPath.row]).jpg")
        cell.imgView.image = img
        cell.nameLable.text = namelist[indexPath.row]
        cell.bountyLable.text = "\(bountylist[indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    }

// reaction after click
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("--> \(indexPath.row)")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: indexPath.row)
    }
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}

class ListCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLable: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bountyLable: UILabel!
}



// detailviewcontroller

import UIKit

class detail_seannyViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageview: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bountylabel: UILabel!


    var name: String?
    var bounty: Int?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateUI()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func updateUI() {
        if let name = self.name, let bounty = self.bounty {
            let img = UIImage(named: "\(name).jpg")
                imageview.image = img
                label.text = name
                bountylabel.text = "\(bounty)"
        }
    }


    @IBAction func close(_ sender: UIButton) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the delegates properly.In the other case you should use the breakpoints whether the code is going in "didselectrow" method or not.Kindly mention this so that i can help more.

Answer (score 0):

Case sensitivity matters.

`"showDetail"` in `didSelectRowAt` is not the same as `"showdetail"` in `prepare(for segue`

---

Side note:

Don't `guard` cells in `cellForRow`. Force downcast the cell. If the code crashes it reveals a **design** mistake which can be fixed immediately.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ListCell
```